# Have macOS prioritize IPv6 DNS

Tags: networking, macos, router, dns, ipv6

My mac usually has 2 DNS servers registered.

- 10.0.0.1 (opnsense router, retrieved from DHCP)
- OPNSense IPv6 address, retrieved from SLAAC

When the DNS servers are listed, it lists the ipv4 one first, so it uses that one instead of the IPv6 one.  How can I have macOS prioritize the IPv6 DNS?

Or alternatively, if this should be fixed on the server rather than the client, how can I have OPNSense make sure that clients prioritize IPv6 over IPv4?

Comment: Is there anything in particular you're hoping to achieve? Even a DNS server contacted using IPv4 can return AAAA records and whatnot.

Comment: @DanielB well then how can I have unbound return both records, because it's using IPv4 instead of IPv6 when I connect, even if A and AAAA records exist for that domain.

Comment: That probably means your upstream DNS service isn’t working right. Disabling IPv6 in Unbound isn’t as easy as flipping a switch. Try using Google DNS or CloudFlare DNS as upstream.